# How to obtain several values after using Array.filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've successfully filtered my array so that the only objects that display are the ones that contain the string 'eastern' in Course.

```
// Empty array + object that is pushed onto array following Btn click

var dataSet = [];

dataObj = {Course: courseSelect.value, Score: scoreText.value, Pars: parsText.value, Birdies: birdiesText.value};

dataSet.push(dataObj);

// Filter

findVal = dataSet.filter(findVal => findVal.Course === 'eastern');
```

The only problem is now, if I want to isolate just the Score value from that object by using `console.log(findVal.Score)`, it returns undefined. I expect it to return each Score value from each object in the filtered Array, but it doesn't.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: I can't see any array. How does `dataSet` looks like?

Comment: isn't `finalVal` is an array? you would need to access the index

Comment: You posted `dataObj`, but the `.filter()` code involves something called `dataSet`.  Note that `.filter()` returns an *array*, so of course there'll be no `.Score` property directly on that array.

Comment: you have `// Array` above something that is clearly an object

Comment: Sorry everyone, made a mistake with my post. I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: You need to iterate over the remaining Array items in dataSet in order to use `findVal.Score` (this is trying to reference findVal as if it's a singular object whereas it is infact an array of objects). You can see this by trying `findVal[0].Score`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `findVal` it's an array, you should use `map` method in combination with *destructuring* approach in order to get the `Score` property for each of the item from array.

```
findVal = dataSet
           .filter(findVal => findVal.Course === 'eastern')
           .map(({Score}) => Score);
```

Comment: I think destructuring is not useful in this case instead it makes code more dirty. `.map(x => x.Score);` is more cleaner.